# Meteor: what code goes on the client side and server side?

Tags: meteor

I just don't know exactly what I should put on the server side and what on the client side. I understand that the templates goes on the client side. But what about the javascript code? Can you give me an example of some code going on the server side?

Answer (score 5):

You can write all your business logic and complex database operations in your server side code. Typically the code you don't want to serve to the client.

For example.

### Method calls

```
# client-side
Template.post.events({
  "click #add-post": function(e) {
    var post, post_object;
    post = $("#post-message").val().trim();
    post_object = {
      user_id: Meteor.userId(),
      post: post
    };
    Meteor.call("create_post", post_object,(function(error, response) {
      if(error){
        ..do something           
      }else{
        .. do something else        
      });
    );       
  }
});

# server-side
Meteor.methods({
  create_post: function(post_object) {
    return Posts.insert(post_object);
  }
});
```

### publish / subscribe

```
# common
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

# client-side
Meteor.subscribe("posts");

# server-side
Meteor.publish("posts", function(limit) {
  return Posts.find({
    user_id: this.userId
  });
});
```

Html, css and Template managers should go into the client-side code. Meteor methods and publishers should go into the server-side code. Read more about [structuring](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) the app and [data security](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/dataandsecurity) in [official docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full).

Comment: only answer that actually answers the op's question (types of logic/code to handle on client vs server in a typical meteor app).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a collection: Declare, publish and subscribe to it.

Server and client (any directory except `private`, `client`, or `server`, don't use `public` for that too), declare the collection:

```
Rocks = new Meteor.Collection('rocks');
```

Server-side (`server` directory or in a `Meteor.isServer` condition) ,publish the collection:

```
Meteor.publish('allRocks', function()
{
    return Rocks.find();
}
```

Client-side (`client` directory or in a `Meteor.isClient` condition), subscribe to the publication:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allRocks');
```

You can find a lot of examples in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/) or in this [blog (Discover Meteor)](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/).

Edit: For more precision according to OP's question... All code is shared by default (executed by both the server and the client). However, files in the `server` and `private` directory will never be sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. if create a directory named `client` that goes only to client.
2. if you create a directory named `server` that goes only to server.
3. every thing else you code goes to client and server both. (even if
   you use `Meteor.isServer` check)

you can read more about directory structure [here](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files).

Comment: Will the code on the server be visible to the client? I just want to hide some parts of code to the client.

Comment: its simple as creating a directory named `client`. code in that directory on goes to client only

Answer (score 0):

You use Meteor.isClient and Meteor.isServer to load the code in the proper place.

Using the folder:

- server - goes to the server duh!
- client - goes to the client duh!
- both   - shared code

Everything that is placed outside client or server, is loaded on both places.

When you create Meteor package you've to add manually the files and specify where it should be loaded, example:

```
api.add_files(['my-packages.js', 'another-file.js'], 'client');
api.add_files(['server/methods.js'], 'server');
```

On this example althouhg you have a `server` folder, **it doesn't mean that it be placed in the server**, in the package scenario.

Something you've code that is going to run on the client and server but some functionalities might only be present at server or client.

Example:

```
ImageManager = {
  uploadImageToAmazonS3 : function(){
    if(Meteor.isServer){
      //your code goes here
      //YOU DON'T WANT TO SEND YOUR AMAZON PRIVATE KEY TO THE CLIENT
      //BAD THINGS CAN HAPPEN LIKE A HUGE BILL

      var amazonCredentials = Config.amazon.secretKey;
    }
    else{
      throw new Error("You can't call this on the client.");
    }
  }
}
```

This a scenario where you can add functions that the client can do like: resizeImage, cropImage, etc and the server can also do this, this is shared code. Send a Private API KEY to the client is out of question but this file will be shared by the server and client.

Documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-isServer

**According to the documentation this doesn't prevent the code from being sent to client, it simply won't run.**

With this approach an attack knows how things work at the server and might try an attack vector based on the code that you sent to the him.

The best option here is extend the ImageManager only on the server. On the client this function shouldn't even exist or you can simply add a function throwing an error: "Not available".